# Jquery colon conflict

Tags: jquery

HTML allows to use as a valid identifier (ID) a colon. For example:

```
<div id="item:0">...</div>
```

The problem is I have a Jquery snippet like this:

```
$("#" + id).clone(true, true);
```

When some ID uses a colon this call makes JQuery crash. What can I do to make it work? (Note: changing colon symbol for other valid character is not an option)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the id with something like

```
id = id.replace(':', '\\:');
```

before you try selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

You say changing the id is not possible - but could you change the id with javascript client side?

Otherwise, you could assign a class to each element that has id with colon, and select them by their class.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you clone a div, not by id?